# How to set index and foreign keys in EF 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

#### UPDATE

***I dropped the table and add the table clean with the suggestions and it looks good now so see the updated content.***

The following error `ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN failed because column 'Id' does not exist in table 'Region'.` results when trying to define the table constraints.

I assume this statement,   `RenameColumn(table: "dbo.Region", name: "Id", newName: "OrganizationId");`,  in the migration script (below) is the root but I don't understand why it wants to rename the `Region.Id` (the PK) to `OrganizationId`...I'm guessing because the org id is used more than once and it's tripping upthe magic ef config...?

This is the source table (with correct constraints):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Region]
(
      [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
      [OrganizationID] [int] NOT NULL,
      [Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
      [ParentRegionID] [int] NULL,

      CONSTRAINT [PK_Region] 
          PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
      CONSTRAINT [uqc_Region_OrganizationID] 
          UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Id] ASC, [OrganizationID] ASC)
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Region]  WITH CHECK 
     ADD CONSTRAINT [Organization_Region_fk] 
     FOREIGN KEY([OrganizationID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Organization] ([Id])
 GO

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Region] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Organization_Region_fk]
 GO
```

Model config:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Region>()
            .HasKey(k => k.Id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Region>()
            .Property(i => i.Id)
            .HasColumnAnnotation(
                IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName,
                new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("uqc_Region_OrganizationID", 1)));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Region>()
            .Property(o => o.OrganizationId)
            .HasColumnAnnotation(
                IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName,
                new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("uqc_Region_OrganizationID", 2)));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Region>()
            .HasRequired(o => o.Organization)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(o => o.OrganizationId);
```

Entity classes:

```
public class EntityBase
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Region : EntityBase
{
    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public int ParentRegionId { get; set; }
    public Organization Organization { get; set; }
    public Region ParentRegion { get; set; }
}

public class Organization : EntityBase
{
    public int? ParentOrgId { get; set; }
    public int? OrganizationTypeId { get; set; }
    public int TimeZoneId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationEmployeeMap> ApplicationEmployeeMaps { get; set; } = new HashSet<ApplicationEmployeeMap>();

    public virtual ICollection<Facility> Facilities { get; set; } = new HashSet<Facility>();

    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; } = new HashSet<Employee>();

    public virtual ICollection<Organization> Organization1 { get; set; } = new HashSet<Organization>();

    public virtual Organization Organization2 { get; set; }
}
```

The migration script:

```
           public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Region",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    OrganizationId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    ParentRegionId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 255),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Organization", t => t.OrganizationId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Region", t => t.ParentRegionId)
            .Index(t => new { t.Id, t.OrganizationId }, name: "uqc_Region_OrganizationID")
            .Index(t => t.ParentRegionId);
        
    }
    
    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Region", "ParentRegionId", "dbo.Region");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Region", "OrganizationId", "dbo.Organization");
        DropIndex("dbo.Region", new[] { "ParentRegionId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.Region", "uqc_Region_OrganizationID");
        DropTable("dbo.Region");
    }
```

Comment: Posting the relevant entity classes would help. From what I see, the multiplicity of the relationships looks incorrect.

Comment: @IvanStoev I added the entity classes and tried another recommendation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont know why

but it should be the correct map between region and organization

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Region>()
            .HasRequired(me => me.Organization)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(me => me.OrganizationId); //FK property
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this code is building the additional foreign key, treating it as a self-referencing foreign key

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Region>()
        .HasRequired(p => p.ParentRegion)
        .WithRequiredDependent();
```

Comment: @Don_Sartain Thanks this helped but it was a combination of things that helped resolved it. I would mark yours as an answer as well if I could

Comment: @WillLopez No worries. I wasn't sure which part you were asking about, so I answered the part that Carlos didn't.